# __V for property variable in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have JMX structure such as,

- ThreadGroup-1

  - Set propertyVariable-Content_0,Content_1,Content_3 etc
- ThreadGroup-2

  - LoopController
  - Counter-counterNum

    - HTTPRequest--use PropertyValue as ${__V(__P(Content)_${CounterNum})}

above variable is not fetching value.

Got stuck on how to use __V for this case as it has property variable.

can someone explain me how to use __V when we have property variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) here, you can access property value using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) directly like:

```
${__P(Content_${CounterNum},)}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Property Across Thread Groups]

In case of malfunction double check that you're **really** setting the properties values using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) listener combination

Answer (score 0):

you need to use this

```
${__V(MainVriableName_${CounterNo})}
```

1) Add Loop Controller

2) Under Loop Counter -> Add Counter (Starting value= 1, Increment = 1, Maximun value = ${MainVriableName_matchNr} and Exported Variable Name = CounterNo

3) After in the below Request(s) use  ${__V(MainVriableName_${CounterNo})}

this works fine.

Comment: Hi Richard ,If you see the question like i mentioned i have to take my variable value from the different thread group.